# How can I get the function/action name that custom attribute is attached to while it is executing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, action-filter

Ideally, I want to create a filter that inherits from ActionFilterAttribute that I can apply in Global.asax that will create performance counters for all the actions in my application.  That problem is easy, but the issue is that I want the performance counters to have the method signature of the action that they are attached to in their name.  However, I can't find a way to extract the method name of the method that an attribute is attached to during construction.  This is causing me to have to apply the attributes to each action individually and pass in their signature as a parameter.  However, this poses obvious problems (i.e. updates to method signature not automatically synchronized with perf counter naming).

To simplify the problem, if I attach an attribute to a method of any kind, can I access the name/signature of the method that it is attached to?  I'm looking for a generic solution that works for attributes that don't derive from ActionFilterAttribute also.

```
public class SomeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string FunctionSignature { get; set; }

    public SomeAttribute() 
    {
        this.FunctionName = { HOW DO I GET THE NAME OF THE METHOD I'M ON WITHOUT PASSING IT IN AS AN INPUT ARGUMENT? }
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // Some code to update perf counter(s) with recorded time that will use string.Format("{0}: Avg. Time or Something", this.FunctionSignature).
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) 
    {
        // Some code to record time.
    }
}

[SomeAttribute]
public void SomeMethod()
{
    // Some code.
}
```

Comment: Did you try `filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName`?

Comment: Also `filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"]`?

Comment: `ActionFilter` is meaningful for actions not for any kind of methods.

Comment: I did not because I explicitly wanted a generic solution that could work even for attributes that don't derive from ActionFilter.  Ideally, I want to get it while in the constructor.

Comment: I think you should use an external method, that will use reflection to find actions with this or another attribute, and write info into the log. There is no way you can find to what method an attribute will be attached in its constructor (AFAIUI).

Comment: @ideafixxxer I'll try that.  I did try using an external method to set the function name; however, there is some funkiness with how the lifetime is managed.  The class variables of the attribute are not preserved unless they are stored during construction, so setting them after they've been constructed didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Find the name of executing action:**

```
var actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
```

or alternatively

```
var actionName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"] as string
```

**Find parameters (Name, Type, DefaultValue):**

```
var parameters = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters();
```

**Find parameters values:**

```
 var value= filterContext.ActionParameters["parameterName"];
```

Comment: Yes. You understood my question correctly.  However, the performance counters are created in global.asax when the application starts.  So, at that time, there is no filterContext for the attribute, which is why I needed to be able to get the method's name/signature during construction.  The only way I could get this to work is if the value in the filterContext is exactly the same as the value obtained from reflection during construction.  I can try this; however, I am looking for a solution that works even for attributes that don't derive from ActionFilterAttribute.

Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you want generic solution for that, not related to ActionFilterAttribute or asp.net at all. Then you can use Aspect Oriented Programming, and best implementation of that for .NET is PostSharp. Free version of that library is enough to achieve your goal. For example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    [Measure]
    public static void Test() {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public sealed class MeasureAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{        
    private string _methodName;
    [NonSerialized]
    private Stopwatch _watch;
    public override void CompileTimeInitialize(MethodBase method, AspectInfo aspectInfo) {
        base.CompileTimeInitialize(method, aspectInfo);
        // save method name at _compile_ time
        _methodName = method.Name;
    }


    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args) {
        base.OnEntry(args);
        // here you have access to everything about method
        _watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    }

    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args) {
        base.OnExit(args);
        if (_watch != null) {
            _watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Method {0} took {1}ms", _methodName, _watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }

    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args) {
        base.OnException(args);
        // do what you want on exception
    }
}
```

Here we create MeasureAttribute which you can apply on *any* method and intercept method invocation in many points. Even more, you can even apply it dynamically to all methods based on some condition (i.e. all methods in given class or whole assembly, or whatever). It also allows you to save some information in *compile* time, to increase perfomance. In example above we save method name once during compilation.

PostSharp (and AOP in general) can do much more than that.

Comment: This seems interesting. I will look into it!  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Forgot to mention that to install PostSharp - just install their nuget package, no need to download anything.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your method name will be the same as `filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName`.

And you can get the Controller instance from `filterContext.Controller`.

So having class and method name you can get the signature, however not in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I am looking for a solution that works even for attributes that don't derive from ActionFilterAttribute that might want to utilize the signature of the method they are attached to.  I also want to be able to get this value in the constructor because of how the lifetime of attributes managed.

Comment: @BrandonPhillips Honestly, I don't think it's possible or should be possible. My understanding is that attributes are objects, "attached" to different language constructions. Thus, how do they know at the time of instantiation to what method they will be attached to? Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: That makes perfect sense, but it would seem that if the way that an attribute is used is to be attached to something else, then it should have access to the context (e.g. at the very least the identity) of whatever it is being attached to.  It probably isn't possible, but I wanted to make sure before I gave up on the idea.  However, I think it is worthwhile to have access to the identity of whatever I'm attaching to if I'm using an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine two alternatives. You could reflect on all the types in classes in loaded assemblies - not very direct but works. Problem is - I'm not sure if the interesting assemblies are even loaded in time - you might have to proactively load them using config information as a guide.

The attributes can be queries on the various MethodInfo/PropertyInfo objects that you can interrogate reflectively. Then, the attributes are queried with [MemberInfo.GetCustomeAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.getcustomattributes(v=vs.110).aspx).

Alternatively, instead of global.asax, you could have the interesting types register themselves for inspection during their static initialization.